# How to reinstall default graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 21.10

I'm running a laptop with an integrated AMD GPU and ubuntu 21.10. I made the mistake of trying to install the mesa drivers from [https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers), however when I rebooted animations were not functioning which appeared to be due to 3D acceleration being disabled. I then followed the uninstall instructions on the PPA page, but 3D acceleration was still disabled.

At this point, I think the best option would be to switch back to using the default drivers that ship with ubuntu. How would I do this? All other posts I can find about this are either specifically for nvidia/intel or are several years out of date.

EDIT: solved by running `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf`. Turns out the uninstaller for the official AMD video drivers leaves a file that blacklists the regular drivers from loading...

Comment: You could have used `ppa-purge` that automatically removes the PPA and everything that was installed from it in one go, in this case it would downgrade many packages to the original versions. Simply removing a PPA after the fact does not remove what was installed from it.

Comment: That is what I did and is what the instructions on the PPA page said. Perhaps I should have made that clearer in the post.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: All packages up to date. Maybe I should try reinstalling ubuntu?

Comment: Well, unless someone else can give a better solution, reinstalling is certainly a good option.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. I'll wait around a few hours and see if anyone has a solution, otherwise reinstall time it is.